# Thread count of process x?

Tags: applescript, unix

My AppleScript needs to get thread count of process x.

I have tried many ps etc codes but all these are not working for some reason.

I tried these:

```
do shell script "ps uH p 301 | wc -l" -->"       0"
do shell script "ps axo pid,ppid,rss,vsz,nlwp,cmd" --> error "ps: nlwp: keyword not found
```

Answer (score 3):

`ps` on OS X takes different options than `ps` on Linux. Please have a look at `man ps` to see the detailed list of supported keywords. For threads I found the following (but I don't know whether this is the information you are looking for):

```
 wq         total number of workqueue threads
 wqb        number of blocked workqueue threads
 wqr        number of running workqueue threads
```

PS: I would recommend to first test any unix level commands in Terminal/bash and only move to AppleScript once they are working as expected. You are far more flexible in bash and also may get better/more helpful error messages back.

Comment: There seems to be a distinction between "workqueue" threads and threads as reported by Activity monitor. For example, Chrome reports 31 threads in Activity monitor, but `ps` reports 1, 1 and 0 for `wq`, `wqb` and `wqr` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

`ps -M PID | grep -v USER | wc -l` will give the thread count. Replace `PID` with the process ID of the process in question. The `-M` option prints one line per thread of the process, then `grep` strips out the header line, and `wc -l` gives the count.

The AppleScript will end up being something like `do shell script "ps -M " & process_id & " | grep -v USER | wc -l"`, where `process_id` is an AppleScript variable.